# DRF: Image page not found

Tags: python, django, imagefield

I want to add ImageField to my module and follow the instruction

Serializer returns **http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/images/lkdj/unnamed.jpg**
but the link doesn't work (Page not found)

How can I receive a valid link?

Added

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/' # 'http://myhost:port/media/'
```

**models.py**

```
def name_image(instance, filename):
    return '/'.join(['images', str(instance.name), filename])


class Construction(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=name_image, blank=True, null=True)
```

**views.py**

```
class ConstructionView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = ConstructionSerializer
    queryset = Construction.objects.all()
    pagination_class = ConstructionSetPagination

    def get_construction_create_serializer(self, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer_class = ConstructionSerializer
        kwargs["context"] = self.get_serializer_context()
        return serializer_class(*args, **kwargs)
        
    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_construction_create_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.perform_create(serializer)
        headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
        response = {"result": serializer.data}
        return Response(
            response, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)
```

**serializer.py**

```
class ConstructionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    coordinates = PointField()
    deadline = serializers.DateTimeField(format=TIME_FORMAT)
    cameras_number = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Construction
        fields = (
            'id', 'developer', 'name', 'image', 'address', 'coordinates', 'deadline',
            'workers_number', 'machines_number', 'cameras_number',
        )
        read_only_fields = ('workers_number', 'machines_number', 'cameras_number')
    
        def create(self, validated_data):
            instance = super().create(validated_data=validated_data)
        return instance
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this in the urls.py in the project.

```
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: I have already added this line, but didn't solve the problem

Comment: I can see image in my directory, but url did't return image

Comment: Try it by running python manage.py collectstatic once